# Revealing module pattern combined with ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, es6-modules, revealing-module-pattern

I don't know which approach is better with ES6 modules and the revealing module pattern. Is the data / functionality from an ES6 module as private as an IIFE?

Should I just use *only ES6 modules, like so:

```
// Export file

export const test = () => {
 console.log('Hello from test');
}

// Import file

import { test } from "./test.js";

test();
```

Or should I use *both combined*:

```
// Export file

export const revealingPattern = (function() {
    function test() {
        console.log('Hello from test');
    }

    return {
        test
    }
})();

// Import file

import { revealingPattern } from "./test.js";
revealingPattern.test();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main purpose of the revealing module pattern is to keep data encapsulated, but the top level of an ES6 module is *already* private - variables defined in it do not leak to the global scope (unless you assign to the global object explicitly, like `window.foo = 'foo'`).

So, in an ES6 module, there's not really any point to the revealing module pattern - feel free to define whatever you want on the top level, and it'll be scoped to the module (and only the module), and then you can explicitly `export` whatever needs to be revealed (and nothing else will be undesirably revealed).